# Restart nodes in state down

Tags: centos, slurm

after a power outage my nodes went to state **down**

**sinfo -a**

```
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
partMain  up      infinite      4   down* node[001-004]
part1*    up      infinite      3   down* node[002-004]
part2     up      infinite      1   down* node001
```

I do these commands

```
 /etc/init.d/slurm stop
 /etc/init.d/slurm start
```

**sinfo -a**

```
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
partMain  up      infinite      4   down node[001-004]
part1*    up      infinite      3   down node[002-004]
part2     up      infinite      1   down node001
```

how could I restart my nodes ?

---

**sinfo -R**

`REASON               USER      TIMESTAMP           NODELIST
Not responding       root      2019-07-23T08:40:25 node[001-004]`

```
$ scontrol update nodename=node001 state=idle    
$ scontrol update nodename=node[001-004] state=resume

# the state changes to idle* but for a few seconds then returns to down*

$service --status-all | grep 'slurm' 
slurmctld (pid 24000) is running... slurmdbd (pid 4113) is running...


$systemctl status -l slurm
● slurm.service - LSB: slurm daemon management
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/slurm; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-07-24 13:45:38 CEST; 257ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 30094 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/slurm stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 30061 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/slurm start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 30069 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try with this after initiating the daemons:

`scontrol update nodename=node001 state=idle`

Comment: hello, i get this error:  **slurm_update error: Invalid user id**

Comment: Check slurm.conf and if the slurm user is the same that yours.

Comment: I had to put myself as root, the command does nothing, the nodes remain in the down state but sets by setting the state to **resume** *scontrol update nodename=node[001-004] state=resume* (@damienfrancois) the state changes to **idle\*** but for a few seconds then returns to **down\***.

Comment: Check if the slurmd daemon is still running, because it doesn't look like that. If it crashes, read why in the log.

Comment: `$service --status-all | grep 'slurm'  slurmctld (pid 24000) is running...  slurmdbd (pid 4113) is running...`

Comment: I said slumd, and in every single node.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't know what command I need to type to get this information.

Comment: The same, but for the "slurmd" daemon instead of "slurmctld".

Comment: you will need to run that command on the compute nodes. and make sure the `slurm.conf` is the same on all nodes, and the if of the slurm user is the same, and munge is running correctly. If the `slurmd` is not running, start it on one compute node with `slurmd -Dvvv' and look for errors.

Answer (score 8):

See the reason why they are marked as down with `sinfo -R`. Most probably, they will be  listed as "unexpectedly rebooted". You can resume them with

```
scontrol update nodename=node[001-004] state=resume
```

The `ReturnToService` parameter of `slurm.conf` controls whether or not the compute nodes are active when they wake up from an unexpected reboot.

Comment: hello i edited my post and added `sinfo -R` output. for **ReturnToService** i have **2** as value for this parameter.

Comment: make sure to run the `scontrol update` command as root or as the user specified in `slurm.conf` parameter `SlurmUser`

Comment: I continue the discussion on @Bub Espinja's line so as not to duplicate the answers